# Google Chrome Script vs parser

Tags: google-chrome

I have this question regarding the network tab in google chrome, under the intitator column
scripts are labeled as being fetched from the script and some are being labeled as being fetched by the parser;

what is the difference between the 2 initiators?

Answer (score 0):

Those acquired from the Parser are acquired from parsing the HTML document itself (i.e. they are the content of `<script>` tags/sources).  Those acquired from Script are acquired by the running of scripts.

Comment: ok so does that mean that the parser is slower then the script loads?

Comment: @user2097441 I don't think so ... if anything I would expect Parser to be faster, but it probably depends on where the script is loaded from

Comment: why would that be? would not the script have to be parsed first to fetch the scripts

Comment: @user2097441 it's parsing the HTML, not the script.  The JavaScript does get parsed, but it gets parsed if it's retrieved from Script too.